# Prepare in-store app for MDM deployment

Tags: ios, app-store, mdm, airwatch

I have a free app in the app store.

A company asked me to provide an IPA file for deployment with their MDM system (Citrix AirWatch - I never heard of it before). I am not completely sure what they need, but I have tried to export from archive using "Save for Enterprise Deployment", which gives me the error

> "To save for Enterprise Deployment, you need to add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in the iOS Developer Program.

My account is enrolled in the iOS Developer Program and I have a valid developer cert in the keychain; I can successfully deploy to the App Store.

So I guess since I am not a company, I am not allowed to make Enterprise Deployment, and it's the customer who would have to sign the IPA with his Enterprise key, right? Can I just send them the unsigned IPA, or is this a security hole? Can I just send them the IPA as signed for the app store and they deploy it outside the store? Or should/could they download the IPA from the store by themselves?

(Not completely sure about their intentions, either. Can they take my unsigned ipa, change the copyright notice, sign it for the store and distribute it there?)

Comment: To deploy an enterprise app you will need to enroll in the enterprise program. So you could send them the unsigned IPA but better ask them to add you to there developer program. Than you can create the IPA from them

Comment: @rckoenes I don't have an enterprise, but even if I did, I would not be allowed to deploy to outside my own enterprise, right?

Comment: True, but the company you are developing the app for can invite you to their development account.

Comment: I told them "RTFM" (well, I said it a bit more kindly) and the customer has found out how to deploy the app that already is in the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AirWatch, you can deploy any app which is in the App Store. You can install automatically on any device or on-demand and users choose whether to install it or not.

To do so, go to your AirWatch Admin Console, in Apps & books, section Public. Click on "Add Application" and you'll be able to browse the App Store and deploy any free app.

If you use VPP (Volume Purchase Program), you can assign license to your users so they don't need an Apple ID. That's particularly interesting for paid apps.

To do so, go to the VPP Console and purchase any free or paid app. You'll get a spreadsheet of your order which you have to import in your AirWatch Admin Console, in Apps & books, section Purchased.